# DBcontext, dynamically specify connection string

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string, dbcontext

I'm dealing with a C# application using EntityFramework and an object derived from DbContext.
I need to set programmatically the connection string when a new instance of MyDbContext object is created. In order to do so I use the following code:

```
public MyDbContext(string myString)
{
    this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = myString
}

myString =  "Server=MYSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MyDB; User ID=user; Password=pass;";
or
myString =  "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\AirecCalcDatabase.sdf";
```

The database providers are different for the two strings. SQLExpress for the first one, SQLCompact for the second one.
If I try to run this code with the first string, I get ArgumentException coming from the connection string. For example "Keyword not valid: server" but also "Keyword not valid: database". The connection string works when using the DbContext with no arguments, which is, reading the string from app.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're wanting to use CE, you may need to change the [DefaultConnectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.defaultconnectionfactory%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to point to SQL CE:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
```

See [this blog post](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/code-first-entity-framework-unit-test-examples/) for more information

Comment: To what should I set the Database.DefaultConnectionFactory if I want to use an SQLexpress server?

Comment: You can use new [SqlConnectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.sqlconnectionfactory(v=vs.103).aspx), with a connection string.  See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbconnectionfactory(v=vs.103).aspx) on msdn for more info.